# How can I export a .pst file that includes all the "Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange" items?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, export, pst

I'm trying to export a folder with subfolders in Outlook, but there are a bunch of emails I want to export that are only on MS Exchange. For example:

[image]

How can I download all of these into Outlook so that when I export to a .pst, it includes all of these older emails? Note that when I click that link, then go to the next folder to click that link there, the files from the previous folder seem to be forgotten and are once again only on the server. So I can't go folder to folder clicking the link, then export and get them all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Outlook Offline Settings, move the slider to the right side. You could also use Online mode, then all the previous mails will download to the client.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!